# Daily mean of hourly data per parameter

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following data frame that shows hourly simulated heavy metal concentrations for two parameters:

```
Date<-c("2013-01-01 02:00:00","2013-01-01 03:00:00","2013-01-02 02:00:00","2013-01-02 03:00:00","2013-01-01 02:00:00","2013-01-01 03:00:00","2013-01-02 02:00:00","2013-01-02 03:00:00")
Parameter<-c("Par1","Par1","Par1","Par1","Par2","Par2","Par2","Par2")
sim1<-c(1,4,3,2,6,5,3,5)
sim2<-c(3,2,3,1,8,2,7,3)
obs<-data.frame(Date,Parameter,sim1,sim2)
obs$Date<-as.POSIXct(obs$Date)
```

I need the daily mean for each parameter. Any ideas? I tried to `aggregate`but I couldn´t figure out how to group by parameter and date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the 'Date' to `Date` class with `as.Date`, use that in the group_by along with 'Parameter' and get the `mean` of the rest of the columns with `summarise_all`

```
library(tidyverse)
obs %>% 
   group_by(Daily = as.Date(Date), Parameter) %>%
   summarise_all(mean)
```

---

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ Date + Parameter, transform(obs, Date = as.Date(Date)), mean)
```

Or using `by`

```
by(obs[3:4], list(obs$Parameter, as.Date(obs$Date)), FUN = colMeans)
```

Comment: The `aggregate` option works like a charm. However, I figured that there was a dot missing just after the opening bracket: `aggreate(.~Date + Parameter, transform(obs, Date = as.Date(Date)), mean)

Comment: @Matt Sorry, I copied it wrong.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Corrected